# CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server not Express and when db grows to 10240 I get error:

> Could not allocate space for object  in database because the 'PRIMARY'
>   filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files,
>   dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the
>   filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the
>   filegroup.

I tried to change Initial size from 10240 to more but then got error:

> CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting
>   cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB
>   per database. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1827)

But this is really not Express but full SQL Server, so how it is possible that it has this limitation?

Comment: What does `SELECT @@VERSION` tell you?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4033.0 (X64) 
 Jul  9 2014 16:04:25 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor) so this is express ?

Comment: So that is Express Edition.

Comment: then why in sql server it tells me mssqlserver ? not sql express ?

Comment: Which part of ***Express Edition** with Advanced Services* makes you think this is ***NOT*** Express ?? It ***is*** Express , and therefore it's limited to 10 GB :..

Comment: It said Microsoft Corporation `Express` Edition :)

Comment: The instance name is only *by default* `SQLEXPRESS` - but it **can be anything** ..... you **cannot** rely on the instance name to judge Express or not - as you've just learned..... if you install SQL Server **Express** as the **default** (un-named) instance, then you get `MSSQLSERVER` as the pseudo instance name ....

Comment: You should copy this as answer

Comment: Could you read only 10 GB of the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instance name for SQL Server Express is by default `SQLEXPRESS` - but it can be anything you choose during installation. If you install SQL Server Express as the **default** (un-named) instance, then you get `MSSQLSERVER` as the pseudo instance name for SQL Server Express.

Hence, you really cannot rely on the *instance name* to judge whether your SQL Server is the Express edition or not. You need to use

```
SELECT @@Version
```

to get that information.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same error in my Express Edition as the official documentatios says, to fix it without shrink the DB I upgraded my version, from Express to Developer edition. Go to  SQL Server Installation Center->Maintenance->Edition upgrade.

Answer (score 8):

You need to upgrade from "SQL Server Express" edition to "SQL Server Developer" Edition from "SQL Server Installation" under "Maintenance".

Answer (score 0):

issue is due to SQL server express version, Uninstall the current version of sQL EXPRESS VERSION install the developer editionand try it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your first answer! Unfortunately, your answer need some improvements. The author wrote: "I have SQL Server not Express" - you negate it, so this is not the answer. And one suggestion: please, use any kind of editor with autocorrection, this is not an English text ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You need to upgrade your SQL server version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30902083)

Answer (score -5):

this is may be due to lack of space in your computer.

Comment: No, when you get a message specifically complaining about hitting a licensed size limit, it's not anything to do with available storage space on the computer.